# Working repeating alarmmanager doesn't work, receiver doesn't start

Tags: android, fragment, alarmmanager

```
public void schedule()
{
    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10*1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

Above this is my method in a Fragment. Also tried in Activity. Weirdly this code works on an empty test project. The problem as I've seen here is that the last part, `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` does not start the `AlarmReceiver.class` at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

my Manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

also my receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered and SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think that better solution would be set new alarm thing in your receiver. Because sometimes it might go wrong so you can ungister it and not repeat in some circumstances.

Comment: Use setRepeating, setInexactRepeating batches together your alarms to be triggered when the OS senses free time and adequate resources. Also please take note of how alarms work for API level 19.

Comment: @Rafik991 thanks but the problem is the receiver doesn't start 'at all'

Comment: @NunChai i did try that, but sadly it doesn't work either

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of setInexactRepeating. Use setRepeating and it will be processed at the right time.

Instead of:

```
setInexactRepeating
```

use

```
setRepeating
```

setInexactRepeating, is OS and battery friendly, it batches together all the work to be done on Alarm receive and works through one by one, while as setRepeating instantly fires the alarm

Also a note: Alarms are wiped off once phone is rebooted, you might have to implement a boot broadcast receiver to make it persistent. Make sure you dont do that runtime, you need to implement it in the Manifest else when your app is not in background you will not receive any broadcasts.

#### A small example:

**This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.**

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

**Set Alarm from Service:**

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:**

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

And create new class:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: umm, as I've said above, setRepeating doesn't work either sadly, I did try that

Comment: The above is working code, in a live app with almost 5000 users.

Comment: I know, I've seen it before, I went through your code and found my mistake. I was declaring the receiver wrongly in my manifest file. I have to declare it like: <receiver android:name="com.test.AlarmNotifReceiver"/> thanks a lot! why the android:process=":remote" though?

Comment: Dont mind that, its for  abackground service which will be executed on the alarm.

Comment: ah so I don't need it, thanks again! I just had to read through another code again

Comment: I have to ask, the CancelAlarm() method here doesn't work, is there a reason for that? everything else works just perfectly.